# is it possible to make push notifications to all devices which had installed my application without Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?

Tags: java, android, rest

I want make a push notification when there is data insert to table of the database. I use REST API in android using retrofit. Could it possibly to make push notification every "insert" to all devices without firebase cloud messaging???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCM is just a framework that allows you to send push notifications. I know that Samsung has their own framework that they use. And maybe there are others.
So, technically it's possible to create your own framework to do this, but I would never recommend it. There is so much to consider to get this done correctly (power use, security, registration of devices, etc. etc.) and using FCM is quite easy.